# OnInit and __init__ in wxPython

Tags: python, constructor, wxpython

I am learning wxPython. In one of the examples, the code is like follows:

```
import wx

class App(wx.App):    
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title = 'bare')
        frame.Show()
        return True


app=App()
app.MainLoop()
```

And I noticed that class `App` has no constructor but a function `OnInit`. As far as I know, Python classes are constructed with `__init__` function.

So, is `OnInit` functions are for specific classes? Or it is another type of constructor?

Please forgive my ignorance since I am new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`wx.App.__init__` documentation](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.App.html#wx.App.__init__):

> You should override `OnInit` to do applicaition initialization to ensure
> that the system, toolkit and wxWidgets are fully initialized.

-> `OnInit` method is only for classes that derive `wx.App`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got the code from "wxPython in Action" book- good book would recommend,

It goes on to say (Im sure you have red this by now)...

> Notice that we didn’t define an **init**()method for our application
>   class. In  Python, this means that the parent method,
>   wx.App.**init**(), is automatically  invoked on object creation. This
>   is a good thing. If you define an **init**() method of your own, don’t
>   forget to call the **init**()of the base class, like this:

```
class App(wx.App): 
     def __init__(self): 
         # Call the base class constructor. 
         wx.App.__init__(self) 
         # Do something here...
```

> If you forget to do so, wxPython won’t be initialized and your OnInit()method  won’t get called.